# VS Code does not find own python module in Workspace

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pythonpath

I am working on a python package with VS Code with the following layout of the opened workspace folder in VS Code

```
workspace
| + tests
| | - test1.py
| | + other_tests
| | | - test2.py 
| + mymodule
| | ...
```

What I want is to call in `test1.py` and `test2.py` the package `mymodule` with

```
import mymodule
```

When I do this, I always get the error `no module named 'mymodule'`. I know i can load the path via inserting the following to all test files:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('<path_to>/workspace/')
```

Then `mymodule` is correctly loaded. (I know I can use `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent[n]` for some `n` to get `<path_to>`.

But this process is really cumbersome if you have many test files in different folders... and it is just ugly.

Is there any way, to tell VS Code to always include the `workspace` in the path?

I tried a `.env` file with

```
PYTHONPATH=<path_to>/workspace/
```

and I also tried to add the following to `launch.json`:

```
"env": { "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}" }
```

Both did not do the trick. (I am also not sure if `PYTHONPATH` is at all the right solution to my problem, i just tried it ^^).

### In short:

I would like to tell VS Code, that it should always include `workspace` to the search path whenever a python function tries to load a module, regarding the location of the function, so I do not have to call `sys.path.append('<path_to>/workspace/')` in every single main file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the python interpreter is importing a package, it looks for the package in the following locations:

> the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
>
> PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
>
> the installation-dependent default.

So if your package and script file are in the same directory, it will be easily found. But obviously you chose a different directory. Then you have to use the methods mentioned in your article to specify the path to the interpreter, such as modifying the **PYTHONPATH** environment variable or using the `sys.path.append()` method.

Here's a suggestion for another approach. Put your package where python can find it, say under the `lib` folder. This way you don't need to use the `sys.path.append()` method at the beginning of each file.

[image]

*I am using a virtual environment*

**UPDATE:**

You can use virtual environments. it won't make a difference. If you are worried about some factors and do not want to use it, there is no problem. Just find the `lib` folder in your current environment and put your package in it.

for example ( *As far as my machine is concerned* ) :

[image]

The `lib` folder corresponding to the interpreter of this environment is in:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib
```

---

[image]

The `lib` folder corresponding to the interpreter of this environment is in:

```
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Lib
```

*PS :* It can also be placed in the `site-packages` folder one level below the `lib` folder.

Comment: Oh okay, that is i nice solution. So you suggest to place the module within my virtual environment? I am not rely sure if i want to go this route, i am working with git and i think the virtual environment should be setup on each PC separately and not be part of the synchronized files. But it would definitely solve my problem as stated above!

Answer (score 1):

**Option #1 (Recommended)**: Split into a separate package

Since what you are basically looking for is to have `mypackage` as a full-blown package accessible to all the code in this environment, why not do that?

Just separate `mypackage` into a separate pip package, and then "install" it using `pip` into a virtual environment that you are using within this project.

**Option #2**: Use `PYTHONPATH`

From Python's [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html):

> PYTHONPATH: Augment the default search path for module files. The format is the same as the shell’s PATH: one or more directory pathnames separated by os.pathsep (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on Windows). Non-existent directories are silently ignored.

Visual Studio Code definitely [supports setting `PYTHONPATH` through `.env`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable):

> The PYTHONPATH environment variable specifies additional locations where the Python interpreter should look for modules. In VS Code, PYTHONPATH can be set through the terminal settings (terminal.integrated.env.*) and/or within an .env file.

However, you have to be careful about the following note (same page, two paragraphs below):

> When PYTHONPATH is set using an .env file, it will affect anything the extension does on your behalf and actions performed by the debugger, but it will not affect tools run in the terminal.

So, if you are trying to run your project from the terminal directly, this will not work.

Comment: Okey, i realized that both mentioned approaches, ``.env`` and ``launch.json`` worked, but only in debug mode and not when running the code in normal mode through VS Code. But that is kind of useless, if this only affects debug mode. So i guess i either have to make it a installable  package, or keep working with the relative paths...